# Why is turning on the heat tripping the air handler breaker in my new central air system?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I got a complete new air system last year and for some reason when I turned the heat on it was making the breaker associated with the air handler trip. The contractor was nice enough to come back and put in a new breaker for free but the problem continues.

The breaker gets very hot after turning the heat on. I never had this problem before with my old system and I am wondering if a lack of a heat pump could be the problem.

I don't know if I had a heat pump in my old system. I live in Florida and that's why I did not get the heat pump.

Comment: Is this the first season you have used the furnace? How long does it take for the air handler breaker to trip after the heat comes on? Does it trip if you just turn the fan on?

Comment: Is this a heat pump with electric heat strips for auxiliary heat?

Comment: With the heat off, turn the fan to on. Does the breaker trip?

Comment: Florida is a good place for heat pumps. It’s the frigid states that don’t use them.

Comment: Where in Florida is this?

Comment: What is the size (amperage rating) of the breaker that is tripping? Is it a two-pole i.e., 240 V breaker? Do you have electric an resistance heater in the air handler and is it on the same circuit as the air handler motor?

Comment: Yes, is that breaker a two-pole breaker, and what make/model is it? Also, what make and model is the electrical panel in question, for that matter? (if you can't identify the latter, post photos of it, *including labeling*, and we can try to help)

Comment: And if you want to log in from another device, [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) on the device+browser you wrote this on, if you haven't already.  I.E. tie it to an email+password, or Facebook, or Google.